# Why does my program produce no file output?

Tags: c

I am working on a lab assignment which asks me to take a given number from a user, and output that many Fibonacci numbers, test case being 20. I am also asked to have all program output be put into a file named csis.txt. I think that I have done everything correctly in regards to the syntax, but I get a blank csis.txt file. Does anyone see why I am getting blank output files? Does anyone know how I can get each iteration of the for loop to be included in the output? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fp;

int fib(int num);

int main(void) {

int num, num1 = 0, num2 = 1;

fopen_s(&fp, "csis1.txt", "w");

printf("How many Fibonacci numbers would you like to output?\n");
fprintf(fp, "How many Fibonacci numbers would you like to output?\n");
scanf_s("%d", &num);

printf("The Fibonnaci sequence up to %d numbers:\n%d\n%d\n", num, num1, num2);
fprintf(fp, "The Fibonnaci sequence up to %d numbers:\n%d\n%d\n", num, num1, num2);
printf(fib(num));
fprintf(fp, fib(num));

fclose(fp);
return 0;
}

int fib(num) {

int fibnum, counter;

int num1 = 0, num2 = 1;

for (counter = 3; counter <= num; counter++) {

    fibnum = num1 + num2;
    printf("%d\n", fibnum);
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", fibnum);
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = fibnum;
}

}
```

Comment: `printf(fib(num));` should cause compilation errors. If you don't see errors then the first thing to do is adjust your compiler settings, as it is causing you to waste time by running an erroneous program.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Have you been able to write any program that successfully writes to the file? Does the expected `printf` output appear? Does the program create the file if you remove it first (this is to check that it writes a file *in the directory that you expect it to*)?

Comment: @M.M I did not get any compilation errors, but I now realize that I do not need to use the printf to call the function.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, That is why i'm confused as to why it didn't work in this program. The program creates the file, but is blank.

Comment: Please fix your compiler settings to cause errors for the original code, otherwise it will cause you to waste time trying to run erroneous code . (This is not a joke)

Comment: @M.M Can you point me in the direction of how to do this?

Comment: It depends on which compiler you are using

Comment: @M.M I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 free version, And I use the c compiler for it

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with that one but try `/Za` or `/permissive-`